# Create constant in laravel model while use onother constant as key in array

Tags: laravel

I want to create a multidimensional array constant in the laravel model. The array key should be another constant define in the same model or in another model. For example

```
const MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE = 'PR00000001';
const MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY = 'PR00000002';

const TENURE_LIMIT = [
                  'PR00000001' =>  // want to define const MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE here
                      [
                         'min' => '12', 
                         'max'=>'60'
                      ],
                  'PR00000002' =>  // want to define const MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY here
                      [
                         'min' => '180', 
                         'max'=>'240'
                      ]
                ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a function and call that function to get the variable as follow:

```
class A{
    const MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE = 'PR00000001';
    const MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY = 'PR00000002';
    public static function tenure_limit()
       {
           return [
                           static::MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE =>
                               [
                                   'min' => '12',
                                   'max'=>'60'
                               ],
                           static::MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY =>
                               [
                                   'min' => '180',
                                   'max'=>'240'
                               ]
                       ];
       }
}
```

and use like this:

```
A::tenure_limit();
```

Answer (score 1):

My Answer is quite similar to @gbalduzzi, just I want to specify how to access the array more specifically (& also I had almost completed my answer :) )

You can create a class to define all your constants.
Lets say ProductConstant.php

```
class ProductConstant{
    const MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE = 'PR00000001';
    const MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY = 'PR00000002';
   
    const TENURE_LIMIT = [
                          self::MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE => [
                               'min' => '12', 
                               'max'=>'60' 
                           ],
                          self::MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY => [
                               'min' => '180', 
                               'max'=>'240'
                           ]
                        ];
}
```

Then you can use it in some other class,

```
use App\ProductConstant;

$minmaxarray = ProductConstant::TENURE_LIMIT[ProductConstant::MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE];
//will give ['min' => '12', 'max'=>'60' ] as output.
```

Comment: I agree, that is a neat way of accessing the array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self` to reference a const on the same class

```php
class MyModel extends Model {
  const MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE = 'PR00000001';
  const MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY = 'PR00000002';

  const TENURE_LIMIT = [
    self::MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE => [
      .... your data ...
    ],
    
    self::MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY => [
      .... your data ...
    ],
  ];
}
```

If they on a different class, just use the class name instead of 'self':

```php
class Constants {
  const MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE = 'PR00000001';
  const MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY = 'PR00000002';
}
```

```php
use App\Constants; // Here put the path of your Constants class

class MyModel extends Model {

  const TENURE_LIMIT = [
    Constants::MASTER_PRODUCT_COMMERCIAL_VEHICLE => [
      .... your data ...
    ],
    
    Constants::MASTER_PRODUCT_LOAN_AGAINST_PROPERTY => [
      .... your data ...
    ],
  ];
}
```